# form-data | axios: Unable to get headers from FormData, Error: getHeaders is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, form-data

I am trying to post text and file fields using `form-data` and `axios`, but I am getting an error: `getHeaders()` is not a function. Below is my `submit` code, note that I am using `React` with `Typescript`.

```
import * as FormData from 'form-data'
import axios from 'axios'

submit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
  event.preventDefault()

  const { title, description, pictureFile } = this.state

  let data = new FormData()
  data.append('title', title)
  data.append('description', description)
  data.append('picture', pictureFile)

  axios.post('/api/route', data, {
    headers: data.getHeaders() // ERROR: getHeaders is not a function
  })
    .then(res => handle(res))
    .catch(err => handle(err))
}
```

The particular header I am interested in is the `Authorization`, I can set it manually, but then the boundaries are required so ... I better try to get that `getHeaders()` function to work.

I don't get the problem here, `getHeaders` seems to be part of `form-data` API.

Please help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`form-data` is used only on `Node`, if you run it on the browser, it will switch to the `window's` version of `FormData`. I saw this in their code.

```
module.exports = typeof self == 'object' ? self.FormData : window.FormData;
```

Comment: so... how did you get the headers?

Comment: I'm also interested ! ... How to get that "boundary" ?

Comment: Long time ago, but I think I finally removed the `form-data` package and managed to add the Auth header using the browser's FormData.

Comment: Could you please provide some example code?

Answer (score 2):

I Have faced this issue because I wanted to do some unit testing inside nodejs but my code will be used in browser later on.

Here are two solutions that worked for me:

you can define `getHeaders` function in FormData class:

```js
declare global {
 interface FormData {
  getHeaders: () => {[key: string]: string};
 }
}

FormData.prototype.getHeaders = () => {
 return { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' };
};
```

Or you can just write a ternary statement:

```js
axios.post('/api/route', data, {
    headers: data.getHeaders ? data.getHeaders() : { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' };
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Our solution uses [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish coalescing assignment (??=))](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). Works both node and browser.

```
const headers = form.getHeaders?.() ?? : { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' };
```